# Mysql insert row ignoring current transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, insert, innodb, myisam

I have a MySQL table implementing a mail queue, and I use it also to send mails which reports unexpected errors in the system. Sometimes these unexcepted errors ocurrs inside a transaction so when I rollback the transacion also I undo the row inserted (the mail which is reporting the unexpected error) in the mail queue table.

My question is how can I force to insert a row in a table in the middle a transaction ignoring the possible transaction rollback?. I mean, If the transactions finally rollsback, not to rollback also the row insertion for the email reporting the error details.

This table can be read by multiple asyncronous process to send the mails in the queue, so in this scenario the rows have to be blocked to send only once the emails so is not possible to use a MyISAM table type and is using Innodb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you implement a proper asynchronous mail queue without trying to (mis)use RDBMS features?

Comment: @N.B. I beg to differ: A RDBMS is a perfectly valid mail queue. All the RDBMS-based MTAs out there agree with me.

Comment: @EugenRieck Where did I say it's not valid? It doesn't fit the scenario well here, transactions are being used but the queries need to "survive" a rollback. That implies design failure and different approach might be a better solution than trying to force certain data to survive a rollback.

Comment: @N.B. I read you saying **implement a proper asynchronous mail queue without trying to (mis)use RDBMS features** as not being a valid solution.

Comment: Using transactional db for asynchronous mail queue **is** wrong unless there are locks placed at records selected that are to be processed. Nothing stops 2 async processes to access the same record unless a read lock has been put in place. So yes, in this case I'd implement a **proper** async queue (service) that wouldn't share the db connection and fail the insert into the reporting table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `INSERT` should survive a `ROLLBACK` of the transaction, it is safe to say, that it is not part of the transaction. So what you should do is to simply move it outside the transaction. There are many ways to achieve that:

- While in the transaction, instead of running you `INSERT`, store the
  fields in session variables (these will survive a `ROLLBACK`), after
  the transaction run the insert from the session variables
- Rethink your schema - this reeks of some deeper-lying problem
- Open a second DB connection and run your `INSERT` on this one, it will not be affected by the transaction on the first connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a different connection to the database to insert the errors and it won't be in the same transaction context, so they would be inserted.